# Why is Code Deploy not running in new instances generated from an Auto Scale Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-codepipeline

I've setup a Code Pipeline where code is being successfully pulled from Github after every commit and then a Build phase runs specs and then a Deploy phase creates a Deployment pointing to amy Application's Deployment Group and the code is successfully delivered to all my Auto Scaling Group running instances.

The problem comes when a new instance is launched automatically whenever load is too heavy. The new instance comes to life and works great except the latest code isn't there. Why is the AWS Deployment not being run in new instances even if my target is the Auto Scaling Group?